# How to send request to google server in php using a stored refresh_token or a password?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api

My goal is to manage to use the Google APIs in general, in particular here i need to send emails using Gmail API.
I saved in the DB the 'refresh_token' given to me from Google Server the first time i did the login (using Gmail credentials), and now, as written into the guides, it seems that I have to do a server request (I'm using PHP) to the google server like the following.

[I looked also here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008tKWIAY
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl
]

My code is the following:

```
$data = //'grant_type=refresh_token'.
        //'&refresh_token='.$refreshtoken;    (first option)
          '&grant_type=password'.
          '&username=mygmail'.
          '&password=mypasswordgmail';    (second option)
          '&client_id='."xxx".
          '&client_secret='."yyy".                      


$additional_headers = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          $ch = curl_init($token_url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $additional_headers);
          $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
          $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
          if ( $status != 200 ) 
          {
                echo 'token_url: '.$token_url."<br>";
                echo 'params: '.$data."<br><br>";
                echo 'response: '.$server_output."<br>";
                die("Error: call to URL $token_url failed with status $status<br>");
            }                   
            curl_close($ch);
```

And what I get as an answer is something like (using password):

```
response: { "error": "unsupported_grant_type", "error_description":     "Invalid grant_type: password" }
Error: call to URL https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed with     status 400
```

Or (using the refresh_token):

```
response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }
Error: call to URL https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed with status 400
```

I use this in the rest of the code:

```
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
$redirectUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$gclient = new Google_Client();
$gclient->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
$gclient->setAuthConfig('client_secret/client_secret.json');
$gclient->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);     
$gclient->setAccessType('offline');         
$gclient->setApprovalPrompt('force');       
$gclient->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");
$gclient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose");
$gclient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify");
$gclient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly");
$gclient->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
$gclient->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
```

what's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server), requests to the Gmail API must be authorized using OAuth 2.0 credentials. You should use server-side flow when your application needs to access Google APIs on behalf of the user, for example when the user is offline. This approach requires passing a one-time authorization code from your client to your server; this code is used to acquire an access token and refresh tokens for your server.

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google) regarding your `"Invalid grant_type: password"` error. It suggested to specify [`access_type=offline`](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) in your request.

Here's an additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28148401/5832311) which might also help.

Comment: Thanks abiel. I specified the offline type either, still same error.